# Masonary grid issue: grid-auto-rows and gridRowEnd

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I'm having trouble understanding this javascript code:

```
rowSpan = Math.ceil(
    (item.querySelector(".card-content").getBoundingClientRect().height +
      rowGap) /
      (rowHeight + rowGap)
  );
  item.style.gridRowEnd = "span " + rowSpan;
```

Even though I set:

```
grid-auto-rows: 0
```

but some of the cards still have white space at the bottom (see image)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBMcc.jpg)

You can find my codes here: https://github.com/thusmiley/galleria.git

Test site: https://thusmiley.github.io/galleria/

I want to get rid of the white space under the images and understand better why the layout changes when you refresh the site a few times.

Appreciate your help